# Traces the outline of an object in Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to trace the outline of an object in a binary image in Java in an OpenCV project. I tried some algorithms for this purpose.

Actually I get what I want but the code which I wrote was a little bit longer. So I am looking for new solutions about this problem.

I looked at this site: [bwtraceboundary.m in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) and it is perfectly fit to my problem (details are more clear in this website so I do not explain it too much).

So, my question is that; are there any implementations of this function or how can I do the same operations in Java?

Note: Matlab's Java Builder may be useful for me but for now I am looking for a simpler solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Use opencv findContours.

Comment: You may be looking for http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html